# Onetomany domain mapping using azure cosmos sql api

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb

I am doing spring boot application to perform crud operation using azure cosmos db (SQL API).I need to store the data in two different tables.current it is storing into only one table. i missed mapping between those two domains.can any one help me ?

how to give one many mapping in to store the list item details in database.
currently whole data   storing listdetails table only.

```
@document(collection = "list_details")
public class ListDetails {
    String id;
    String name;
    List < ListItemDetails > listItems;
    //setters and getters
}

@document(collection = "list_item_details")
public class ListItemDetails {
    String id;
    String name;
    // setters and getters;
}
```

Comment: @document(collection="list_details")
public class ListDetails{

string id;
string name;
List<ListItemDetails> listItems;
\\seters and geters
}

@document(collection="list_item_details")
public class ListItemDetails {

string id;
string name;
//setters and getters;

}

Comment: you can edit your question and put the code there

Comment: added sample code above.any mapping need to be added. please help me

Comment: Got the answer , in cosmos Db we can not maintain the relationships. whole object need to be persisted in single table